# Table Content Extraction Section wise in .docx file

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.9 to extract table contents from a .docx file.This doc contains multiple tables under different sections.I could extract all the table contents irrespective of the sections , but i want to extract table content under particular sections only.Can anyone help ?

.docx outline:

Section 1: ABC
          Table 1: 
          Table 2: 
Section 2  :CDE
          Table 3: 
          Table 4:

Table Extraction Code:

```
XWPFDocument documentContent = new XWPFDocument(inputStream); 
                                    Iterator<IBodyElement> bodyElementIterator = documentContent.getBodyElementsIterator(); 
                                    while(bodyElementIterator.hasNext()) 
                                    { 
                                             IBodyElement element = bodyElementIterator.next(); 
                                             if("TABLE".equalsIgnoreCase(element.getElementType().name())) 
                        {   
                                                     List<XWPFTable> tableList =  element.getBody().getTables(); 

                             //Extract the table row name and their corresponding values from the word stream content 
                                                     tableRowValues = getTableRowValues(tableList); 

                        } 
                                    }
```

Method:
private static ArrayList getTableRowValues(List tableList) {

```
            ArrayList<String> tableValues = new ArrayList<String>(); 

          for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : tableList) 
        { 
            List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows(); 

            for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) 
            { 

                List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells(); 

                for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) 
                { 

                 List<XWPFParagraph> para = xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs(); 
                for (XWPFParagraph xwpfTablePara : para) 
                { 
                if(xwpfTablePara!=null) 
                           { 
                     tableValues.add( xwpfTablePara.getText()); 

                           } 
                } 


                } 
            } 
        } 
          return tableValues; 
    }
```

Comment: Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I did about the same thing.
With this code I extract all the sections with tables underneath it :

```
 Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = xdoc.getBodyElementsIterator();

               while (iter.hasNext())
               {    

                  IBodyElement elem = iter.next();

                  if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph)
                  { 
                      relevantText.setText(((XWPFParagraph) elem).getText());
                      relevantText.addBreak();
                      relevantText.addCarriageReturn();
                  }

                  else if (elem instanceof XWPFTable)
                  {     
                      relevantText.addBreak();
                      relevantText.setText(((XWPFTable) elem).getText());
                      relevantText.addCarriageReturn();
                  }

               }
```

You can create an `if-statement` before the `getText()` so it only extract text when the right conditions are true.
In example you can check on; styles, text etc.

```
paragraph.getStyle() //filters on word styles, eg ""header1"
paragraph.getNumFmt() //filters on bullet text
```

For more see the documentation from `Apache`
https://poi.apache.org/